# Interpolation substitution on JSON string Using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

config.ini

```
request = {"order": {"order_id": {order_id},"customer_id":10001, "prd_price":50, "quantity":{quantity}, "total_price": {total_price}, "product_id":1, "last_name": "lavanya"}}
data = {'quantity': '315', 'total_price': '50', 'order_id': '102'}
```

myscript.py

```
req = config[reflowStep]['request']
req = req.format(**data)
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "myscript.py", line 247, in reflow
    req = req.format(**data)
KeyError: '"order"'
```

Expected Output:

```
req = { 
"order":{  
      "order_id":102,
      "customer_id":10001,
      "prd_price":50,
      "quantity":315,
      "total_price":50,
      "product_id":1,
      "last_name":"lavanya"
   }
}
```

If I pass as a string(without '{/}'), it's working. 
For eg:

```
request = "order_id": {order_id},"customer_id":10001, "prd_price":50, "quantity":{quantity}, "total_price": {total_price}, "product_id":1, "last_name": "lavanya"
```

But my requirement is I need to populate the values into the json at runtime.

Anyone, Could help me? Could anyone suggest the best way for my requirement?

Comment: How is `req` supposed to be a dict and a string (using `format`) at the same time? Also, `request = "order": ...` is invalid syntax and will clearly not work. Are you missing some `"` in your examples? Also, how does `reuqest` relate to `config[reflowStep]['request']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using JSON for your configs if you need JSON data - INI format is quite limited in that regard and there can be various artifacts if you try to cram JSON in it.

That being said, if your only problem is field interpolation while using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) you should escape your curly braces using double braces (i.e. `{{` and `}}`) to achieve the desired effect, i.e.:

```
request = '{{"order": {{"order_id": {order_id}, "quantity":{quantity}, "price": {price}}}}}'
data = {'quantity': '315', 'price': '50', 'order_id': '102'}

print(request.format(**data))
# {"order": {"order_id": 102, "quantity":315, "price": 50}}
```

Or if you want it formatted:

```
print(json.dumps(json.loads(request.format(**data)), indent=2))
```

Yielding:

```
{
  "order": {
    "order_id": 102,
    "quantity": 315,
    "price": 50
  }
}
```